# deleting a image file yii

Tags: image, file-io, yii

can any one pls tell me how to delete an image file and directory in yii

I have tried unlink but its not working.(the path is correct but its not deleting) but getting the error **No such file or directory**

```
unlink(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/uploads/'.$model->file_id.'/'.$fileModel->file_name.$fileModel->extension);
```

- and I also need to delete a directory in yii framework.the path is
  correct but its not deleting

  rmdir(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/uploads/'.$model->file_id);

This is not working either, but getting the error **No such file or directory**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
unlink(getcwd().'/uploads/'.$model->file_id.'/'.$fileModel->file_name.$fileModel->extension);
```

`getcwd()` gets the current working directory. The docs for it are [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Comment: Thanks alot eskimo ;)..you saved my day frn :) Its working for both file delete and rmdir delete as well.. thanks again :)

Comment: no problem. file paths are weird sometimes, but getcwd() usually seems to do the trick

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

> Yii::app()->request->baseUrl

Try

> Yii::app()->basePath

Comment: Thank for your reply. i tried with Yii::app()->basePath as well but no use such file or directory error.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used Yii's earlier versions.

For Yii2: unlink(Yii::$app->basePath.'/directory_path/'.$filename);

Answer (score 0):

we can use this as well

```
unlink($file->getFullPath());
```